# C# UWP passing Parameter Backward

Tags: c#, uwp, parameter-passing, back

is there a way to pass data to the previous page when the back button is pressed and the BackRequested command is executed. When navigating forward, I use the following code:

```
 this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Warenkorb), groups);
```

Can someone help me?

Edit:

I tried it with static fields. It is there another way?

Comment: The feature you're trying to implement makes sense to you, but it won't be as clear to the user. Going to a previous page generally means that the page won't be updated (and if it were, the page would update itself on loading, rather than expecting to receive updates from the other page when clicking on the back button - which is not intuitive). Your proposed approach leaves much to be desired and is going to create problems for you down the line. I would reconsider your approach and look at having pages automatically get the latest data when they are loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do here is to use MVVM paradigm instead of raw code-behind spaghetti. Having MVVM, you're provided with a structured understanding of what's going on in your app, at which state it is right now etc. So, let leave the navigation for the its general purpose - showing and hiding pages. Do not try to put too much over it, keep the app state in MVVM.

Comment: While I agree with everything you've said, this isn't really a complete answer. No references, no concrete explanation, this answer boils down to "use [thing]".